# how to use custom dimension in batchGet

Tags: google-analytics-api

When I try to do batchGet with custom dimension I get an error "Unknown dimension(s):"

This code works fine

```
analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet({
    requestBody: {
        reportRequests: [
            {
                viewId: 'XXXXXXXXX',
                dateRanges: [
                    {
                        startDate: '7daysAgo',
                        endDate: 'today',
                    },
                ],
                dimensions: [
                    {
                        name: 'ga:eventCategory'
                    }
                ],
                metrics: [
                    {
                        expression: 'ga:totalEvents',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
})
```

but when I use for dimension a custom analytics dimension , replacing ga:eventCategory with ga:store

```
dimensions: [
             {
             name: 'ga:store'
              }
           ],
```

I am getting  Error: Unknown dimension(s): ga:store

The dimension "store" is working on analytics GUI

[image: The dimension "store" is working on analytics GUI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the reporting API you need to refer to the dimension by its index rather than its name. This is because the name can change over time, but the index never does.

Assuming `store` is in index `2`, then you would use this code:

```
dimensions: [
             {
             name: 'ga:dimension2'
              }
           ]
```